# Auto Responder SMS-gateway Yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2, cron-task

I'm new in Yii2, now I'm using Yii2 with the advance template.

In my project, I need my application can read database using AJAX, and also run in background task. It's like a Cron Job, but I don't know how to do it.

Anyway, I want to integrate sms-gateway services, so when I create some request, it send SMS to user,  and user can send SMS to the application with some format. And the SMS from user, it will be used to do another action in my project.

After all, I just can send SMS from my application to user, but cannot read SMS that send from user, and then I can't trigger another action.

Just the same on Yii2 Forum [over here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63442-askauto-responder-sms-yii2/)!

Comment: please post the part of code which you are using to trying to receive sms. Also, the sms provider you are using must have given you a code/guide to receive sms.

Comment: I'm using gammu services in my project. 
After all, i just can send SMS from My Yii2 Application. 

And SMS from user, it saved to database, but i want, each new SMS will trigger another function in My Yii Application .. 

Is it possible to do ??

Comment: As now it seems you have solved the main issue and have incoming SMS stored to db, you can either use the incoming sms receive function to trigger the 'another function' or alternatively , build a yii command and run it using cron at scheduled intervals to scan for all new incoming sms messages and trigger relevant action for each of them

Comment: i've tried using yii command, and  scan incoming sms  with  the smallest scheduled time only every  1 minutes . How can i scan it realtime, so i can scan every 1 second or 10 second maybe.. ? 

could you help me please... ??

Comment: instead of using cron for trigger, you should make your own php loop that continously checks the last id in the sql table (say every 1 to 3 sec to keep performance impact low). if the last id is changed, read the 'delta' messages and do the action  with a max delay of only a second to 3 seconds. Again, you can reduce this time even further at cost of performance however a better approach is to generate a trigger from the script which is saving the sms to db in the first place (if you can explain why it does not do that it would be great)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not understand what did you mean..
If i do that, is it will scan the incoming sms, even the browser is inactive?

Could you show me some example code to do that please...
Maybe some code snippets or pseudo code, that can bring me understand what did you mean..., Sir.. Please.. 

May be you can post the code by answer this question...

Comment: i mean the program that is receiving the sms and storing to db, can that trigger a command?

Comment: Absolutely no. The program only store to db,. And we only scan the incoming sms from db, so that i need a realtime scanning. If any new sms come, it will scanned and processed.

More specific what i mean it's like `sms polling`. So we must scan all incoming sms, and validate it. But i need the scanning work on background process. I've tried using ajax too, but if the browser closed. It won't scan the incoming sms.

Comment: you can use yii command and run it from cli in an infinite loop with timer delay to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I use infinite loop with sleep in 1 second. So it will check the database every seconds, that do action that check incoming sms and auto  reply the sms.

```
while (true) {

 /*Other script that will read sms , and reply sms*/ 

  sleep(1);
  //Or use usleep to use sleep in microsecond

}
```

more about [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)